# HP 625 AMD Turion heat, suspend, fan speed

Tags: suspend, hp, overheating, fan, temperature

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit) on an HP 625 laptop (AMD Turion P540 processor, 4 GB RAM). Everything works smoothly besides the fact that I think that the system mismanages fan speeds and as a result my processor tends to heat up.
If I am on AC power things seem to work fine, but if I unplug my laptop the fan stops and restarts only when temperatures reach very wild degrees (70 C), then spins up heavily. I have the very same problem with suspend functions too, if I wake up the fan is again not spinning.

Any solution? I am not experiencing any of these problems on Windows 7 (I dual boot my system). In fact with Windows 7 my system overall runs 10 degrees cooler (I have lm-sensors installed). What is strange that my laptop originally came with SLED 11, therefore should be fully Linux compatible.

Thanks for help!

Hunor

```
lucifer@lucifer-HP-625:~$ sudo sensors-detect
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: Hewlett-Packard HP 625 (laptop)
# Board: Hewlett-Packard 1475
# Kernel: 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64
# Processor: AMD Turion(tm) II P540 Dual-Core Processor (16/6/3)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): y
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           Success!
    (driver `k10temp')
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             No
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     Yes
Found `SMSC FDC37B72x Super IO'                             
    (no hardware monitoring capabilities)
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): y
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): y
Using driver `i2c-piix4' for device 0000:00:14.0: ATI Technologies Inc SB600/SB700/SB800 SMBus

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x90 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x91 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y
Client found at address 0x28
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM80'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM96080'...             No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D'...                            No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D'...                            No
Probing for `Nuvoton NCT7802Y'...                           No
Probing for `Winbond W83627HF'...                           No
Probing for `Winbond W83627EHF'...                          No
Probing for `Winbond W83627DHG/W83667HG/W83677HG'...        No
Probing for `Asus AS99127F (rev.1)'...                      No
Probing for `Asus AS99127F (rev.2)'...                      No
Probing for `Asus ASB100 Bach'...                           No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1029'...                     No
Probing for `ITE IT8712F'...                                No

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x92 (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x93 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x14 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 10h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)

No modules to load, skipping modules configuration.

Unloading cpuid... OK

lucifer@lucifer-HP-625:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +53.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)
temp2:        +20.9°C  (crit = +108.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +53.0°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +100.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)
```

Comment: Please run sudo sensors-detect accepting all the defaults and then run sensors. Edit the question to show the entire dialog. You can use paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my question and posted the results of sensors-detect.

Comment: Well you have two temperature sensors with temps of 53 Celcius and 20.9 Celcius, plus sensors-detect found something at i2c address 0X28 but could not work out what it was. Does your BIOS support fan control because this is going to be the easiest option? If your BIOS has a hardware monitoring function reboot into it and look at the temperature information (ideally post an image) That will allow us to work out what the two temperatures are.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the end I solved it very easily. In BIOS there was an option that fan always on (and it was set to always on), I suppose that in this case the BIOS controlled fan speed. I set to adjust fan speed according to performance and since problem seems solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have two temperature sensors with temperatures of 53 Celsius and 20.9 Celsius, plus `sensors-detect` found something at i2c address 0X28 but could not work out what it was. Does your BIOS support fan control? Using this is going to be the easiest option?